# Unable to pose rigged character

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

I'm fairly new to blender and am having trouble posing my rigged character. I was watching this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkuOs_VA_y4&t=411s) I thought I got the armature and mesh to connect as the automatic weights edit panel showed up, but for some reason when I go to pose mode and try to move the armature the mesh doesn't move with it. The next step of the video is going into weight paint mode to check all the bones have enough weight and my model is completely blue meaning that the mesh isn't connected at all. I added weight paint to the right spots so the model wasn't completely blue anymore, but the mesh still doesn't move with the bones. I am doing this project on a tight deadline so any help is appreciated.
[image: Model armature]
[image: Weight paint before]
[image: Weight paint after]

Thank you

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hi @moonboots, thanks for the response.
I have uploaded the blend here https://pasteall.org/blend/277b481edf9c4df0be7cac9302df0078

thanks for any guidance you can provide :)

Comment: you have a lot of overlaying layers of meshes, it makes my computer lag, are you sure it is necessary? you should try to simplify as much as possible, it will make the parenting work better I guess

Comment: for example it looks like you've used and applied Solidify modifiers, which doesn't seem necessary

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice @moonboots, I will try and simplify the model and have another go.
Thanks once again !! :)

Comment: yes don't use Solidify, and don't use layers of cloths if possible, the parenting should work much better